# Week Number of the Month with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I like to know if it is possible to make a vba code to find the week number of a date with these conditions:

1. Friday is the first day of the week
2. If the week consists of two months, (for example: May 27,2016 to June 2,2016), the week number will be determined by the number of days in each month. In this case, the number of days in the may part of the week is greater so the week number is equal to 5.

I tried to make a solution in a spreadsheet but I can't seem to figure out how to convert it all into vba code. If anyone has an idea to how this could be done, it is greatly appreciated.

Here is my attempt on the solution:
[spreadsheet (green for input) (blue for output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKrOx.png)
[spreadsheet with formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLXzO.png)

Answer (score 0):

here's a not so elegant solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim date1 As Date, date2 As Date
    Dim weeks1 As Long, weeks2 As Long

    With Worksheets("weeks")
        For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
            date1 = cell.Value
            date2 = cell.Offset(, 1).Value
            weeks1 = DateDiff("ww", date1, "01/01/1900", vbFriday)
            weeks2 = DateDiff("ww", dateadd("d", -Day(date1), date1), "01/01/1900", vbFriday)

            If DatePart("m", date1) <> DatePart("m", date2) Then
                If DateDiff("d", date1, dateadd("d", -Day(date2), date2)) >= 3 Then
                    If IsDate(cell.Offset(-1)) Then
                        cell.Offset(, 8) = cell.Offset(-1, 8) + 1
                    Else
                        cell.Offset(, 8) = weeks2 - weeks1
                    End If
                Else
                    cell.Offset(, 8) = 1
                End If
            Else
                If IsDate(cell.Offset(-1)) Then
                    cell.Offset(, 8) = IIf(cell.Offset(-1, 8) > 3, 1, cell.Offset(-1, 8) + 1)
                Else
                    cell.Offset(, 8) = weeks2 - weeks1
                End If
            End If
        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better algorithm, but here is a UDF that, given any date, will return the Weeknumber of that date according to your specifications (if I have understood them correctly).

You can adapt to your specific requirements as necessary

```
Option Explicit

Function wnMonth(DT As Date)
    Dim dtFF As Date
    Dim dtLF As Date
    Dim lWN As Long

'First and Last Fridays of current month
dtFF = DT + 8 - Day(DT) - Weekday(DT - Day(DT) + 8 - 6)
dtLF = dtFF + 28 + 7 * (Day(dtFF + 28) < Day(dtFF + 21))

If DT >= dtFF And DT < dtLF Then
    lWN = Int((DT - dtFF) / 7) + 1
    If Day(dtFF) > 4 Then
        lWN = lWN + 1
    End If
Else
    If DT < dtFF Then
        If Day(dtFF) > 4 Then
            lWN = 1
        Else
            'First Friday prior month
            dtFF = DateAdd("m", -1, dtFF)
            dtFF = dtFF + 8 - Day(dtFF) - Weekday(dtFF - Day(dtFF) + 8 - 6)

            'Last Friday prior month
            dtLF = dtFF + 28 + 7 * (Day(dtFF + 28) < Day(dtFF + 21))

            'First Friday weeknumber
            If Day(dtFF) > 4 Then
                lWN = 2
            Else
                lWN = 1
            End If

            'Last Friday weeknumber = DT weeknumber
            lWN = lWN + (dtLF - dtFF) / 7
        End If

    Else 'DT > dtLF
    'days left in the month
        If (8 - Day(dtLF + 7)) < 4 Then
           lWN = 1
        Else
            lWN = (dtLF - dtFF) / 7 + IIf(Day(dtFF) > 4, 2, 1)
        End If
    End If
End If

wnMonth = lWN

End Function
```